# Create table with CATALOG_COLLATION fails with syntax error (Copy Azure database to local development SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio generated a script to create database with schema only. Original database is an Azure SQL database.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [library-production]
  WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO

-- Other commands
```

When generated script is executed in the local database (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer (64-bit)), execution fails with an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

I am trying to copy azure database to the local, how I can create database on local instance with script generated from Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is an option of [Azure Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current).

For [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you can use this statement:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [library-production]
  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

Comment: `WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` works for me on a SQL 2019 instance but the collation must match the instance collation.